# Create a property name with the same name as a Keyword

Tags: c#, syntax

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find the answer I need.

I am creating an assembly using C# and one of it's structs is named need. I'm trying to do the following:

```
internal struct need {
    internal need how
    {
        get
        {
            return how;
        }
    }
    internal need true
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a new property named true. need.true
obvious the IDE doesn't like this as I am trying to create a property that has the same name as a keyword.

The obvious fix is change the name to something else, like truth, but my heart tells me that that's not what I should do.

This really peaked my interest. You can theoretically created a variable (or whatever) and the assembly should be able to figure out which variable you are referring to based on the context and scope. If I were to say something like: (pseudo code)

```
create int number
create need.int number
```

Or if I did something like:

```
create int number // In the want struct
create int number // In the need struct
```

There should be no issue for the assembly to determine which type I wanted to create based on the context or scope. The only issue is the IDE doesn't seem to use the correct scope and won't let me build.

I've tried, true, need.true, this.true, etc. all to no avail.

I'm sure that having my assembly determine what "true" is within it's "need" struct is imperative to it's functionality, as the assembly needs to be able to use it's own type of true within a certain scope and context, not what ever the language, or whatever specifies it, has specified it to be.

How do we do this?

P.S. The reason these are properties is so that I could essentially make them read only. Bonus points if you can tell me the way to have them in an internal struct and read only...

Comment: What about True instead for true

Comment: Linked duplicate answers your question (use `@`). Side note: Most people will likely consider naming properties in confilict with reserved words to be an awful idea, but this is strictly opinion based and if you never show your C# code to others it is ok. Please make sure your future SO question not directly related to that problem use regular names and follow default C# naming conventions (i.e. use upper case for classes/properties - `Need`)

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix a `@` before the keyword.

```
internal struct need
{
    // btw your properties will result in a infinit loop
    internal need how
    {
        get
        {
            return how;
        }
    }
    internal need @true
    {
        get
        {
            return @true;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you need to return `true` from that property you will have to implement an `implicit operator need(bool)` :

```
internal struct need
{
    internal need @true
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public static implicit operator need(bool value)
    {
        // todo: initialize it
        return new need();
    }
}
```

Or, change the return type :

```
internal bool @true { get { return true; } }
```

Comment: The only way I knew how to essentially declare an internal readonly "thingy" inside of a struct was to make it a property with only get specified, and no set. The only thing I can get it to return is itself. I thought it would end up returning null or void, not an infinite loop. The assembly just needs to know if the need exists, not what the value inside it is, and will never actually call the need, it will just see if calling is possible (if it exists).
I really don't see how using @true is an different than using the word truth (It isn't?), I want to have it to determine it's own true.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to return `true` in `@true.get`, as the return type is `need` not `bool`. That comment is solely based on from the information given in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Regardless of what it returns etc. you didn't answer the question. I asked how you use the same name as a keyword, and your answer is to use a different name. Not the solution we need...

Comment: If you need to use it exactly as `need.true` for some reflexion hack, then you can't. However, the property name is in fact `"true"` without the `@` if you check it via reflexion

Comment: alright I guess that could work then? I'm actually really unsure as to what exactly placing @ in front of it does. I know you can use it for sting literals, and that's all the I can find of @ in the official documentation. Placing @ in front of it here just appears to be some kind of naming convention that ends up being a different name like using uppercase True, or a completely different name like foobar. There has to be a way to do it maybe the @ does I'm unsure (I keep making edits sorry.)

Comment: "Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include `@` as a prefix. For example, `@if` is a valid identifier but `if` is not because `if` is a keyword." - [C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)